# vb.NET pasting to DGV

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, pasting

I want to paste data from the clipboard to selected cells in a DGV. I found the following link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208281/Copy-Paste-in-Datagridview-Control but I have no clue about C# so I converted the code to VB.net using an online tool. The Copy and cut part is working, but I am not able to paste to the DGV. The code looks like this:

```
 'paste data
Private Sub PasteToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PasteToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    PasteClipboardToDGV()
End Sub

Private Sub PasteClipboardToDGV()
    If DgvLeidingen.SelectedCells.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a cell", "Paste", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

        Return
    End If

    Dim startCell As DataGridViewCell = GetStartCell(DgvLeidingen)
    Dim cbValue As Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, String)) = ClipBoardValues(Clipboard.GetText())
    Dim iRowIndex As Integer = startCell.RowIndex

    For Each rowKey As Integer In cbValue.Keys

        Dim iColIndex As Integer = startCell.ColumnIndex

        For Each cellKey As Integer In cbValue(rowKey).Keys
            If iColIndex <= DgvLeidingen.Columns.Count - 1 AndAlso iRowIndex <= DgvLeidingen.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DgvLeidingen(iColIndex, iRowIndex)

            End If

            iColIndex = iColIndex + 1
        Next
        iRowIndex = iRowIndex + 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetStartCell(ByVal DGV As DataGridView) As DataGridViewCell
    If DGV.SelectedCells.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing

    Dim rowIndex As Integer = DGV.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim colIndex As Integer = DGV.ColumnCount -1

    For Each dgvCell As DataGridViewCell In DGV.SelectedCells
        If dgvCell.RowIndex < rowIndex Then rowIndex = dgvCell.RowIndex
        If dgvCell.ColumnIndex < colIndex Then colIndex = dgvCell.ColumnIndex
    Next

    Return DGV(colIndex, rowIndex)

End Function

Private Function ClipBoardValues(ByVal clipboardValue As String) As Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, String))

    Dim copyValues As Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, String)) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, String))()
    Dim lines As String() = clipboardValue.Split(vbLf)

    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        copyValues(i) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()
        Dim lineContent As String() = lines(i).Split(vbTab)
        If lineContent.Length = 0 Then
            copyValues(i)(0) = String.Empty
        Else
            For j As Integer = 0 To lineContent.Length - 1


                copyValues(i)(j) = lineContent(j)
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Return copyValues

End Function
```

Comment: In `PasteClipboardToDGV` you have this line `Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DgvLeidingen(iColIndex, iRowIndex)` where you select the current cell to paste. You don't actually set the value of it though?

Comment: It is working now thanks! Only 1 little problem comes up now. when I copy paste from DGV to DGV or from notepad to DGV all goes as it is supposed to. but when I copy paste from excel to DGV the cell below the data is cleared, no clue why this happens.

Comment: Set some breakpoints in your loops, and just step through it

Comment: Figured it isnt the code, if you copy from excel (for exampe select 4 cells) and then paste in Notepad it also adds an extra line with no data (so it pastes 5 lines).

Answer (score 0):

In vb code, it needs to put "If cell.Selected Then cell.Value = cbValue(rowKey)(cellKey)", after "Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = DgvLeidingen(iColIndex, iRowIndex)"